# How to check if the url passed to `link_to` is valid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, handlebars.js

I am using a Handlebar template for my rails application. There is a button that adds a segment into the form using this template.

I've made a delete button to delete those segments, which calls a function defined in the controller.

I am linking the function to delete in the handlebar template using `link_to`, and it has a variable `{{id}}` in it. It's the id of the segment added to the form, which is created once I save the form.

But for segments that I just added, and haven't saved yet, deleting them would show me a routing error.

How do I go about to solve it?

Comment: can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: Can you show your code?

Answer (score 0):

In your js code check for presence of `id` and if there's no (element that's not saved yet) - delete element without calling the backend.